# How do I launch an hourly version of anacron?

Tags: linux, automation, updates, cron

I have a cron job (system update) that fires off every hour. However, I would like it to be reset every time the machine resumes from standby or hibernation. The command is already launched at each boot via my .zshenv file.

Basically, I would use anacron for this, but anacron only works for daily tasks. The actual program is very simple, but I want it to launch whenever there has been more than an hour since the last invocation and the computer is running.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps `fcron`?

Comment: Why not just cron / [crontab](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&locale=)? :) I think you can add scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` in order for them to be executed after a suspend/hibernation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141702/how-to-run-a-script-after-the-system-resumes-from-hibernate-suspent-to-disk